# ElasticSearch deletes documents in an index automatically

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, logstash-grok

I have configured an **ELK Cluster** with 5 nodes, one being master and the other slaves.
I index logs in the cluster once a day using logstash. I use a **CronJOB** (script) to copy
the log files to the **configured logstash directory**. I have also **manually** set a **.sincedb path for logstash**.

However, a tricky thing happens. Almost every 3 days, **index seems to be loosing documents and deleting everything prior to certain dates**. **I haven't configured any ILM policy**, nor there is any script performing delete by query or delete full index. Even when calling _cat/indices formatted to show the creation date of te index, I see that it has been created almost 2 weeks ago. However, the documents that should've been for 2 weeks aren't there anymore, and even today it only had documents from 3 days ago.

Does anyone know why could this behaviour be happening or what can trigger it ?

Comment: Anything special in your Logstash configuration?

Comment: It uses GROK to parse Haproxy logs and index to elk. Only added the .sincedb path last time, since i suspected that restarting logstash was recreating a new sincedb file and deleting the docs. Also question, deleting the files from the configured directory in logstash, does it mean that they will be deleted in the index as well ? (As per this case the files for last 7 days are there, but only from the last 3 days are indexed )

Comment: Also the directory where the files are stored for logstash to parse, is shared within VMs , don't know if this adds more details

Comment: Deleting files doesn't delete the corresponding logs in the index as Logstash wouldn't know what to delete

Comment: If you can share the output of `GET _cat/indices?v` at two different time intervals where it shows what you're explaining above, it'd help.

Comment: I currently don't have access to that since this config is in production environment. However, even today (when asked someone to call this api that has access in prod ) it showed in the pic they sent me, that creation date was October 25th, the same date that showed when I last was in prod, which was last Thursday (November 3d)

Comment: Would turning audit logging on show me where the deletion is being triggered from ?

Comment: All I can say is that this is not the normal behavior, so something must be interacting with those indexes, but you don't know what since you don't have access to production. I wouldn't just rely on people who have access to tell you

Comment: Yes, audit logging would log that

Comment: Is audit logging commercial feature ?

Comment: Yes, it's commercial, but you can activate a trial license for 30 days, that would be more than enough

Comment: If I get more info regarding this I will comment here again. Thank you a lot for your help Val.

Comment: Something else that is strange is that deleting the documents separetely would take a whole lot of time, so when making the scripts that would clear the index, I would use the delete api and re-create the index again (along with runtime fields) since it was way faster than deleteByQuery. And index is usually 5GB +

Comment: There are various ways of deleting content... bulk/delete or delete-by-query or delete and recreate index... which ones fits best depends on your use case